# Generators of 2-generated metabelian groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a 2-generated metabelian group, with commutator subgroup $G'$ and abelianization $A$.

Is there an example of such a group $G$, together with two generating pairs $\varphi := (x,y)$ and $\varphi' := (x',y')$ with equal commutators $[x,y] = [x',y']$ such that $\varphi$ is conjugate to $\varphi'$, but not conjugate by any element of $G'$?

I'm happy to assume $G$ finite, if it helps.

No such example exists when $A$ acts faithfully on $G'$. Indeed, in this case, any element $g\in G$ conjugating $\varphi$ to $\varphi'$ but fixing $[x,y]$ must act trivially on $G'$ (since $G'$ is a cyclic $\mathbb{Z}[A]$-module generated by $[x,y]$), and hence $g$ must map to $1\in A$, which is to say that $g\in G'$.

If the action of $A$ on $G'$ factors through $H\le A$, and if $G$ arises as the image of a faithful extension of $A/H$ by $G'$ via the inflation map $H^2(A/H,G')\rightarrow H^2(A,G')$, then an explicit calculation shows this also does not result in an example. (Ie, if $G$ is the fiber product $E\times_{A/H} A$ for a faithful extension $E$ of $A/H$ by $G'$)

Aside: Is it possible to classify nonfaithful extensions of $A$ by $G'$ in terms of simpler data? (E.g., can every nonfaithful extension of $A$ by $G'$ with kernel $H$ be constructed in some way from a faithful extension of $A/H$ by $G'$?)

Comment: Try $G = \langle(1,2,3,4),(1,4)(2,3) \rangle$ dihedral of order $8$, $x=(1,3)$, $x'=(2,4)$, $y=y'=(1,4)(2,3)$, which are conjugate by $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here's a counterexample.

Let $G$ be a central extension of an abelian group such that $G' = Z(G)$. Take any generating pair $\varphi$, and conjugate it by some element $g\in G - G'$. Then $\varphi$ and $g\varphi g^{-1}$ will have the same commutator, but they clearly are not conjugate by an element of $G'$, since $\varphi\ne g\varphi g^{-1}$, and $G'$ is central.

Explicitly, we can take $G$ to be a Heisenberg group: an extension of $\mathbb{Z}/p\times\mathbb{Z}/p$ by $\mathbb{Z}/p$ relative to a nondegenerate symplectic form $\mathbb{Z}/p\times\mathbb{Z}/p\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/p$.